# Convert Id type object to integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to python and i'm trying to do a project for college.
The dataframe model is like this,

[Dataframe structure image]

[image: 1]

I want to generate an integer value for each customer_id, this new value being the new customer_id, where the customer_id appears several times, I would like to convert this value to an integer, so that each time this Id appears it receives it, it always receives the same integer value.

I've tried some procedures so far, but it didn't work, one of them was

```
data['customer_id'] = data['customer_id'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
```

But without success, is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert the id to an integer"? For the first row in your screenshot, what should the integer for that customer id be?

Comment: I want to generate an integer value for each costumer_id, this new value being the new costumer_id.

Comment: And what should the new customer ids be for the example data you show in your question?

Comment: What happened, **exactly**? What does "without success" mean? Please provide a [mcve]. Don't post images of data. We should be able to copy and paste your code and reproduce any errors or behavior you are describing

Comment: I would use original `customer_id` without converting to integer. Converting to integer is only waste of time. You don't need integers.

Comment: @furas Yes I agree, I used the custumer_id in the entire project as it was, but when I started to apply the Collaborative Filtering procedure, for some reason that original custumer_id wasn't working.

Comment: I don't know `Collaborative Filtering procedure` but maybe you should show what is wrong with `Collaborative Filtering procedure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new `dataframe` with the names and the ids using `enumerate` and `unique` like:

```
df_id = pd.DataFrame(enumerate(df['name'].unique())).rename({0: 'id', 1: 'name'}, axis=1)
```

And then merge with the original to obtain the ids for each name:

```
df.merge(df_id)
```

Comment: I tried this one and it worked as well, thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def append_customer_id(customer_ids: dict, customer_id: str):
    if customer_id not in customer_ids:
        customer_ids[customer_id] = len(customer_ids)
        
customer_ids = {}    
customer_id = "random id"
append_customer_id(customer_ids, customer_id)
```

I made a function which takes the **customer_ids** **dictionary** and the **customer_id** you want to add and adds it to the **customer_ids** variable. All of your customer_ids are stored in the customer_ids dictionary. And to see the number the customer_id responds to, you would simply do:

```
number = customer_ids[customer_id]
```

Comment: This one also worked, thanks!!!

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate an integer value for each customer_id :

1. store Unique values of the ID column into array `array_ = df.ID.unique()`
2. make a dictionary of this array `d = dict(enumerate(array_)` then exchange keys and values  `res = dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())`
3. and final step : map this dictionary with the id column `df['newId'] = df['ID'].map(res)`

Comment: Thanks, that's worked as I needed, thanks very much =)